# GLFW Undefined Reference to many things

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, glfw

I have tried several times in the past to write programs using OpenGL in C and C++ on several platforms, every time only to be stopped by the ridiculous dependency and linking issues that inevitably come up.

I am attempting to use GLFW with C++ on a linux system, building using CMake, with absolutely no success.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( GL_TEST_PROJECT )

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
    message("ERROR: OpenGL not found")
endif(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)

set(GL_LIBRARY GL GLU X11)

add_executable(testgl testgl.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testgl glfw3 Xxf86vm pthread dl Xi Xcursor Xrandr X11 ${GL_LIBRARY} m)
```

**testgl.cpp:**

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**`make` output:**

```
Linking CXX executable testgl
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b8b): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1ba3): undefined reference to `XineramaIsActive'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitors':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x672): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryScreens'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [testgl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testgl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried several different changes to the `CMakeLists.txt` file, including removing and adding different dependencies, but it seems that there is nowhere for me to go from here. What do I need to do to get this program to compile?

Answer (score 1):

Using the

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)
```

Does not work for me, but adding them all into

```
set(GLFW_DEPS X11 Xrandr Xinerama Xxf86vm Xcursor GL dl pthread)
```

Does get things working.

So, my `target_link_libraries` looks like this

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} glfw3 ${GLFW_DEPS} ${GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY} )
```

It is possible that I'm not using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` correctly, but you should try just adding the libraries your self. Do be careful about it, their order is important and depending on which version of GLFW you're using they could be different.

That error your getting is strictly because your missing the Xinerama library.

There are two ways to not have to add those libraries manually:

Option 1 is to use `GLFW_LIBRARIES` which you would have to include glfw source into your project as stated here [build with Cmake and GLFW source](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_cmake_source)

Option 2 would be to use the help of `find_package` as described here: [Build with installed GLFW binaries](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_cmake_pkgconfig)

It appears as though you have glfw installed on your machine so I would recommend option 2, in part because I have yet to get option 1 to work and I'm currently having to manually enter the libraries. This is because I don't want to have glfw installed on machine vs having it all contained in  the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to "target_link_libraries()":

```
glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${X11_LIBRARIES}
```

And then add this somewhere above "include_directories" in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
#########################################################
# FIND X11
#########################################################
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${X11_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${X11_DEFINITIONS})
if(NOT X11_FOUND)
    message(ERROR " X11 not found!")
endif(NOT X11_FOUND)
```

Edit #2: And try adding the following to your CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lGL -lpthread")
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to fix the problem... I still get the same output.

Comment: Try adding set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXinerama -lXcursor") to your CMakeLists.txt file before "add_executable"

Comment: That also makes no difference in the output.

Comment: See my second edit (I changed the flags). If that doesn't work (works for me), then I'm not sure. Make sure you have all the libraries installed on your machine.

Comment: The edit doesn't fix it, either. I have made sure that (according to several GLFW tutorials, at least) I have all the required libraries on my computer in their correct versions. I have a feeling something else about my CMakeLists.txt is incorrect, because most examples/tutorials for GLFW Cmake files show much less libraries listed than I have added to mine.